# Vulkan + GLFW : How to write color to screen buffer as unsigned integer(s)?

Tags: c++, shader, rendering, glfw, vulkan

I am learning about Vulkan by creating a little program that will render 3D scatter plots. Every point in the scatter plot has an (x,y,z) position and an rgba color. I am packing the rgba color into a single 32 bit value (8 bits per color channel) and loading all the point data into the vertex shader as an array of vec4 where the first 3 components are the position information, and the color information is packed into the 4th component. The vertex and fragment shader code are as follows:

```
#version 450
//Vertex Shader Code
layout(binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
} ubo;

layout(location = 0) in vec4 inPosition;

layout(location = 0) out flat vec4 fragColor;

void main() {
    //gl_Position = ubo.proj*ubo.view*ubo.model*vec4(inPosition,0.0,1.0);
    gl_Position = ubo.proj*ubo.view*ubo.model*vec4(inPosition.xyz,1.0);
    uint color = floatBitsToUint(inPosition.w);
    fragColor.r = float(color&0xFF)/255.0f;
    fragColor.g = float((color&0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0f;
    fragColor.b = float((color&0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0f;
    fragColor.a = float((color&0xFF000000) >> 24)/255.0f;
    gl_PointSize = 1.0f;
}
```

```
#version 450
//Fragment Shader Code
layout(location = 0) in flat vec4 fragColor;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
    outColor = fragColor;
}
```

I set up my swap chain to use VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM format and VK_COLOR_SPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR color space.

As it stands this code works as intended, but I believe it should be possible to optimize the coloring. Currently I unpack the color information, convert it to floats, normalize, pass to fragment shader, then raster. If I could write out the color values directly as integers somehow I could avoid the conversion to float and division which I think would slightly speed up the rendering, but I can't figure out how to edit the swap chain settings or graphics pipeline to do this properly.

I tried changing the swap chain format to VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UINT, but I get validation layer errors when I try writing a uvec4 out:

```
validation layer: Validation Warning: [ UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-Shader-InterfaceTypeMismatch ] Object 0: handle = 0x230000000023, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE; | MessageID = 0xb6cf33fe | Attachment 0 of type `VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_SRGB` does not match fragment shader output type of `ptr to output vec4 of uint32`; resulting values are undefined
```

I intend for this program to eventually render very large scatter plots (hundreds of millions of points) so I think the optimization is worth it if it is possible (and actually does result in less computations, which may require profiling to verify).

How can I modify my configuration to accomplish this?

Comment: I am too just experimenting with vulkan, so there are way smarter people. I can imagine you could have a R8G8B8A8 image on the GPU that you could use as a texture from which you could sample the color (1 pixel at offset in the image) for each particle. You can thus render everything in one draw call. And you can natively update the color bytes from the CPU.